# SSR angular universal and angular 8 - rendering dynamic html content before api completes

Tags: node.js, angular, angular8, angular-universal, universal

I'm able to dynamically render html for server side rendering using angular 8 and angular universal when I view page source BUT my issue is that I am rendering the dynamic html before the api request has finished loading so I can't see the response in the dynamic html from the view page source - please let me know if you require any further info. I run this command:
i.e. **npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr**
and when I look at the logs and change the url I get a [NetworkError] in the console but the app still runs as expected, I need to figure out a way to load the api response and then render the html into the page view source after the request has finished but I've run out of ideas.

Hopefully one of you guys can help, 
Thanks

Server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'localstorage-polyfill';
import { join } from 'path';
import * as express from 'express';

const compression = require('compression');
const sessionStorage = require('sessionstorage');
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const template = fs.readFileSync('./dist/browser/index.html').toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');



Object.assign(global, domino.impl);
(global as any)['KeyboardEvent'] = domino.impl.Event;
global['window'] = win;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
global['Event'] = win.Event;
global['KeyboardEvent'] = win.Event;
global['MouseEvent'] = win.Event;
global['Event']['prototype'] = win.Event.prototype;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['sessionStorage'] = sessionStorage;
global['localStorage'] = localStorage;


// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4200;
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = require('./dist/server/main');
app.use(cors());
app.use(compression());


// express-engine
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// Protect website from Clickjacking attack
app.use(helmet.frameguard());
app.use(helmet.xssFilter());

//  Proxy API Endpoints


app.use('/api/profileProxy', proxy(
  {
      target: 'http://xxxxxxx1:9004', // target host
      changeOrigin: true, // needed for virtual hosted sites
      // ws: true, // proxy websockets
      pathRewrite: {
          '^/api/profileProxy': ''
      }
  }
));

app.use('/api/searchProxy', proxy(
  {
      target: 'http://xxxxxx.160:9005', // target host
      changeOrigin: true, // needed for virtual hosted sites
      // ws: true, // proxy websockets
      pathRewrite: {
          '^/api/searchProxy': ''
      }
  }
));



app.get('/sitemap1.xml', function (req, res, next) {
  const file = `${DIST_FOLDER}/sitemap1.xml`;

  fs.exists(file, function (exists) {
    if (exists) {
      res.sendFile(file);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('404');
    }
  });
});

app.get('/robots.txt', function (req, res, next) {
  const file = `${DIST_FOLDER}/robots.txt`;

  fs.exists(file, function (exists) {
      if (exists) {
          res.sendFile(file);
      } else {
          res.status(404).send('404');
      }
  });
});

// All regular routes use the Universal engine

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.time(`GET: ${req.originalUrl}`);
    console.log(`req-QQQQQQQQQQ: ${req.originalUrl}`);
    res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
    console.timeEnd(`GET: ${req.originalUrl}`);
    console.log(`req-timeEnd: ${req.originalUrl}`);
});

// Start up the Node server

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

``
```

Comment: Are you using  absolute urls?

Comment: Hi @David in my server.ts file I have the proxy IP addresses and my url looks like this: http://localhost:4200/api/searchProxy/search/jobs?pageSize=100&index=0 - where searchProxy is the IP address from the backend _ i'm currently trying to implement a prerender file to see if that will work

Comment: If you need any other information, I would be happy to provide it - the prerendering didn't work - it shows the same html and saves it to dist/browser/route/index.html and still gives [networkError]

Comment: Can you show your server.ts file? And are you using angular's dev proxy, or a custom one?

Comment: I've updated the post with my server.ts file with the proxy I am using

Comment: also I have reverted back and removed the prerendering

Comment: I can see the url's change in the page view source but I can't see the response from the search results

Comment: If you make the API call following a button click that just performs an ajax request, then it will have no effect on the page original source. You'll be able to see the changes in the browser's html inspector, but it won't have any effect on the source that you can see with View Source. Is it what you are describing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213685/discussion-between-tercou1-and-david).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for people that may come across this issue - I was able to display the data from the api request (in my case the initial search results) in the view page source for SSR by making a GET request in the app.component of my app - thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the code for fixing this issue, I'm currently having problems with my application exactly. I have a page for individual products, and I want to render all the Html including the head tag after the data is completely resolved.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. can you provide the code?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is normal behaviour. Only your original request (e.h. when you type in the site's adress) in the URL bar will be prerendered using angular universal. This prerendered html is what you can see if you use View Source (or Ctrl +U)

Once the page is displayed, the client side angular app takes over. When you click on the search button, it'll perform an API call and get results, which will update the page. You'll see that html using the Html inspector from your browser's debugging tool, but it will have no impact on the original HTML that has been sent by the server

Comment: hi David - there must be a way to display the search results when I navigate to the new route after I click on search, I'm routing to a new component, while executing an api, I just need to find a way to load the results before the html renders on the server side, i'll continue to research and thanks for your reply

Comment: If you want the results loaded before (so prerendered server side), then you need to navigate to the page with the directly from the url bar, not with ajax.